# Wireless DNS needing to be different at home and at work

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-7

One of my users brings his laptop to and from the office.  At the office we have to assign the DNS to be able to access the server correctly.

Is there an easy way to switch between the different DNS settings without my user having to remember how to change the DNS settings?

User is using Windows 7 connecting to a Domain that is Windows Server 2003

Comment: Is your user not using DHCP at home?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DHCP server should be configured to provide the address of your DNS server when it responds to a request for an IP.

The user's laptop should be configured to obtain DNS automatically (from DHCP).

Comment: And if he needs a particular DNS server different from the default DNS server for the scope, you can setup a reservation for his address, and push a particular set of DNS servers just for his system.

Answer (score 0):

Create two batch files for the user to run whenever he needs to change DNS settings with following:

```
> netsh interface ip set dns name="[name of network connection]" static [DNS IP address]
> netsh interface ip set dns name="[name of network connection]" static [second DNS IP address] index=2
```